# How to enable sql server connection on PCF

Tags: sql, spring-boot, pcf

Can we create a common SQL Server connection service to be accessed across all Spring boot application on PCF (Cloud Foundary)

Comment: Give more details why you want do that way, what is the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Currently each java service is connecting to database using application properties file present with in the application. Instead can’t we create one database connection and bind all services to it on PCF?

Comment: you can do that by using Tomcat common connection pool and share the connection pool between apps but that is not recommended for enterprise apps. If you are worried about maintaining properties between the applications then set global config in that way you don't need individual property files.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/